# Rails+PaperClip+jQuery-File-Upload with nested models

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using rails 3 with paperclip and jQuery-File-Upload and they are both great gems but they seems not to play well together, especially with nested models.

In my app,
I have two models: `submission` and `upload`, and :

```
**###submssion.rb:**

attr_accessible :email, :uploads_attributes
  has_many :uploads, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploads, :allow_destroy => true

**###upload.rb:**
belongs_to :submission
has_attached_file :package
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def to_jq_upload
    {
      "name" => read_attribute(:package_file_name),
      "size" => read_attribute(:package_file_size),
      "url" => package.url(:original),
      "delete_url" => submission_path(self),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE"
    }
  end
```

in my form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :uploads do |upload| %>
   <%= upload.file_field :package %>
<% end %>
```

in my controller:

```
def create
    @submission = Submission.new(params[:submission])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @submission.save
        format.html { render :json => [@submission.uploads.to_jq_upload].to_json, :content_type => 'text/html',:layout => false }
        format.json { render json: [@submission.uploads.to_jq_upload].to_json, status: :created, location: @upload }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @submission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end
```

However, every time I upload a file the console give me:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_jq_upload' for #<ActiveRecord:....
```

My question would be: how to access another model's method in current model's controller?

Comment: What do you mean it `does not work at all`? Are you getting a javascript error in your console?

Comment: @Cyle, edited and reformatted

Comment: @frankblizzard, yes, I will post an answer shortly, it's more like a work around

Answer (score 1):

This is a work around:

since `to_jq_upload` is only defined in model `upload`, you have to point to the `upload` model before you can use it, in my case, I am looking at the latest upload, so:

revised `create` method:

```
def create
  @submission = Submission.new(params[:submission])
  @upload = @submission.uploads.last
  respond_to do |format|
    if @submission.save
      format.html { render :json => [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json, :content_type => 'text/html',:layout => false }
      format.json { render json: [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json, status: :created, location: @upload }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @submission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```